# How to call routes in subprojects in Play?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.2

As I read this question occurs quite often, but I don't get it. So sorry for my noobishness.

Got a subproject called "subproject1"

In `conf/routes` I call it with `-> /subproject1/   subproject1.Routes`

In `subproject1.Routes` there is an action like:

```
GET   /admin/rater   subproject1.controllers.Application.rater(id: Int ?= 0)
```

There is a view like `stuff.scala.html` and a link like:

```
<a href='@vvv.controllers.routes.Application.rater()?id=@page.getId()'>asdf</a>
```

Play says `value Application is not a member of object vvv.controllers.routes`, But the action is defined in Class "Application"

The route should be like `vvv.controllers.vvv.routes.Application.rater()`.. but that's also an error.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explanation for subprojects can be found [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/SBTSubProjects).

Per your example, you should define the routes in your subproject as

```
GET    /admin/rate    controllers.subproject1.Application.rater(id: Int ?= 0)
```

Then in the view you would call the route as follows (assuming you pass an id variable to the template):

```
<a href='@controllers.subproject1.routes.Application.rater(id)'>asdf</a>
```

Comment: Probably it was a good idea to define "subproject1" as a real subproject, instead of simply splitting the routes-file. Thanks :-)